# Courtesy and Etiquette

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have a `courtesy` and an `etiquette` tag.  Looking at the questions, there actually does seem to be a difference between the two, which rather surprised me - I was about to do a retag-spree, but it looks like they should be kept separate.

What do the rest of y'all think?

Answer (score 2):

I created `etiquette`, then noticed the existing `courtesy` tag.  I've not investigated enough to see if they're different, but my gut feeling is that they should be combined.

Obviously I think we should keep `etiquette`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I say make a synonym suggestion - see if it takes.

Comment: Unfortunately you need 2500 rep to make synonym suggestions

Comment: See also http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/81/should-the-threshold-for-suggesting-tag-synonyms-be-lowered